# One to many relationship. Got to be a better way than using sub-queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: computers and messages.  It's a one-to-many relationship; multiple messages for each computer.

```
create table computers (
  `computer` varchar(45) not null,
  `status` varchar(25),
  primary key (`computer`)
  );

INSERT INTO computers (`computer`, `status`)
VALUES
('fred','completed'),
('barney','incomplete'),
('wilma','completed');

create table messages (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `computer` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `message` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO messages (datecreated, computer,message) 
VALUES
(now(),'fred','start something'),
(now(),'fred','doing something'),
(now(),'fred','end something'),
(now(),'barney','start something'),
(now(),'barney','doing something'),
(now(),'wilma','start something'),
(now(),'wilma','doing something'),
(now(),'wilma','end something');
```

I am trying to get one row per computer that shows the status and the dates of the start and finish messages.

```
fred  | complete   | 2018-01-29 08:00 | 2018-01-29 08:20
wilma | incomplete | 2018-01-29 08:10 | null
```

Right now I'm using sub-queries to query the message table twice for each computer.  I know that can't be the best way to do this. It pegs the CPU on the database when there are 100s of computers.  I've tried unions and joins to no avail.

```
select C.computer, C.status,
  (select max(M.datecreated) from messages M where C.computer=M.computer and M.message like 'start%') as date_start,
  (select max(M.datecreated) from messages M where C.computer=M.computer and M.message like 'complete%') as date_complete
from computers C
order by computer;
```

Here's a related SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5c929/1

Comment: Could there be repeated "started" and "completed" messages?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Does the MCVE from sqlfiddle not count?

Comment: I'm confused. All the entries are for the same time!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `GROUP BY` and `LEFT JOIN`

```
select *
from computers C
left join
(
  select M.computer, max(M.datecreated) date_start
  from messages M
  where M.message like 'start%'
  group by M.computer
) s on C.computer = s.computer
left join
(
  select M.computer, max(M.datecreated) date_end
  from messages M
  where M.message like 'end%'
  group by M.computer
) e on C.computer = e.computer;
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89d2d3/3)

From the efficiency perspective, you need also index `messages(computer, message, datecreated)`

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize *conditional aggregation* to get those dates:

```
select computer,
   -- in case of multiple rows with start you might better use MIN for the start date
   max(case when message like 'start%' then datecreated end) as date_start,
   max(case when message like 'end%'   then datecreated end) as date_complete
from messages
group by computer
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5c929/21)

Now put this in a Derived Table and join it to `computers`

Answer (score 1):

Left Join and Max

```
select C.computer, C.status,
  max(ms.datecreated) as date_start,
  max(me.datecreated) as date_complete
from computers C
left outer join messages ms on 
  ms.computer = c.computer
  and ms.message like 'start%'
left outer join messages me on
  me.computer = c.computer
  and me.message like 'end%'
group by c.computer, c.status 
order by c.computer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation is very useful for this:

```
SELECT C.computer, C.status
     , MAX(CASE WHEN M.message LIKE 'start%' THEN M.datecreated ELSE NULL END) AS date_start
     , MAX(CASE WHEN M.message LIKE 'complete%' THEN M.datecreated ELSE NULL END) AS date_complete
FROM computers C
LEFT JOIN messages M ON C.computer = M.computer
GROUP BY C.computer, C.status
ORDER BY computer;
```

Technically, the `ELSE NULL` is redundant (omitted ELSE clauses always return NULL); but illustrates the intent. Aggregation functions ignore NULL values, so the expressions filter to the appropriate `datecreated` values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a couple of inner join on the gropued query for get the max datecreated for started  and finished

```
select c.computer, c.status, t1.max_started, t2.max_finished
from computers c
inner join (

  select max(M.datecreated) max_started, computer
  from messages
  where message = 'started' 
  group by computer

) t1 on t1.computer = c.computer
inner join (

  select max(M.datecreated) max_finished, computer
  from messages
  where message = 'completed' 
  group by computer
) t2 on t2.computer = c.computer
```